# Get selected excel cell

Tags: c#, excel

i am trying to paste something in a specific Excel Cell,
but sometimes its paste the data somewhere else.

```
 workSheet = ExcelApp.Worksheets[2] as Excel._Worksheet;
             Grd_Dep_In.SelectAll();
            Grd_Dep_In.Copy();
            Excel.Range DepIn = cellsRange.get_Range("a2");
            DepIn.Select();
            workSheet.Paste();
```

Sometimes its pastes in A2, sometimes not.

So i want to check if a2 is the selected cell.

before i start to paste.
My Code copys in 8 worksheets and generates pivot tables. and sometimes it mess up and copys somewhere else in the excel worksheet.

So what I need:

```
if (activeCell= A2)
{
paste

}
```

But i dont know how to detertimate the active excel cell.

Comment: Could any of these be the answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080741/get-user-selected-range, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230937/getting-the-selected-cells-range-from-a-different-worksheet-in-excel?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686787/excel-vba-get-range-of-user-selected-range-by-mouse?rq=1

Comment: This poster - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968856/vba-paste-range - uses `Cell.Activate()`, and the answer simply uses `Cells(1, 1).Paste`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range) this.Application.ActiveCell;
int row = rng.Row;
int column = rng.Column;

if (row == 1 && column == 1)
{
  // paste
}
```

Comment: So easy :) Thank you very much ;D