# writing into spreadsheet active cell with c#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, ms-office

I wrote a C# winforms program which opens an excel spreadsheet and writes integer value "total" into a cell (I9 in this case). Is there any way I can choose a cell in the spreadsheet and write my integer value in the now active cell?

Here is the code pertaining to my question:

```
    private static Excel.Workbook MyBook = null;
    private static Excel.Application excelApp = null;
    private static Excel.Worksheet MySheet = null;
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openb = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openb.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var name = openb.FileName;
            String filename = DialogResult.ToString();

            excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Visible = true;
            MyBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(name);
            MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[1]; // Explicit cast is not required here
            MySheet.Cells[9, 9] = total;
            MyBook.Save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: button4_Click method opens excel spreadsheet after accumulating total

Comment: You mean having the user selecting the cell and then writing the value in such cell?

Comment: Yes, preferably if they do so via mouse input

Comment: Then, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031551/get-selected-excel-cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a second button.

First one opens (and leaves open) the file you need, as you already have it:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openb = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openb.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var name = openb.FileName;
        String filename = DialogResult.ToString();

        excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Visible = true;
    }
```

Second button writes the value of `total` in the cell the user has selected:

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (excelApp != null && MyBook != null) //sanity check
        {
            MySheet = (Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[1]; // Explicit cast is not required here
            MySheet.Cells[excelApp.ActiveCell.Row, excelApp.ActiveCell.Column] = total;
            MyBook.Save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the help Josh. I just needed to add a line to make sure the spreadsheet pops up.